# Technique for spawning and deleting large number of models quickly

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We are trying to run some tests in simulation.  The procedures are roughly as follows

1. Spawn a large number of models (currently simple spheres) at random positions
2. Run some tests
3. Delete the spawned models so we return to the initial state
4. Repeat

Currently, I am using the ros services `/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model` and `/gazebo/delete_model` to spawn and delete models respectively.

The problem is, spawning a single model takes 200ms, deleting a single model takes 400ms.  Since I need to do this many times, this takes an extremely long time.

Am I doing something wrong that it takes so long to spawn a simple sphere?  Is are there better ways to spawn and delete large number of models, e.g. bulk spawn, or reload the environment?

I am currently running on a system without a GPU but with a fairly powerful CPU and CPU usage isn't maxed out.  Would using a GPU help?

The `sdf` file is as simple as it gets

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <model name="tiny sphere">
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="link">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1.0</mass>
      </inertial>

      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>0.01</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>0.01</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25912/technique-for-spawning-and-deleting-large-number-of-models-quickly/) by [wongrufus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21315/wongrufus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2020-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A model is spawned by sending a message to `~/factory` , and deleted by sending a request to `entity_delete`. The services you mention build on top of those. They do some preprocessing, handle the request, and then wait for the model to (dis)appear.

You can write a world plugin to manage your models as a whole. I.e. provide an interface that processes the models altogether and waits for them in the end. You will get some speedup, but it's still going to take a non-trivial amount of time to complete.

See [gazebo_ros_api_plugin](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp) for reference.

Alternatively, assuming the models are always the same, you could spawn them once, and then only randomize their poses in each iteration. This can happen instantaneously.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wongrufus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21315/wongrufus/) on 2020-10-13**:
It seems gazebo gui gets messed up when rapidly calling `/gazebo/set_model_state` for many objects

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on 2020-10-13**:
Create a world plugin to which you can send all model names and poses. Then the plugin can reposition all models in one simulation step in its update callback.